# Apple Script / Vagrant

Tags: automation, applescript, vagrant

I'm new to apple script, but I'd like to open up Terminal, change the path to where the vagrant up command can be ran and then run a vagrant up. So far I have got to;

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd desktop/development/vagrant/"
end tell
```

If I try the following;

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd desktop/development/vagrant/"
    do script "vagrant up"
end tell
```

This opens up a second terminal and tries to execute the vagrant up from the home location instead of running the command in the terminal window that navigates to desktop/development/vagrant/

My question is; is there a way to either run a follow up command in the original (first) Terminal window or a way to run the cd desktop/development/vagrant vagrant up as one singular command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer;

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script ("cd desktop/development/vagrant/")
    do script ("vagrant up") in currentTab
end tell
```

Comment: Or just use `do script "cd desktop/development/vagrant; vagrant up"`